# what type for working with/comparing memory addresses

Tags: c, macos, pointers

If i'm working with memory addresses specifically, eg when writing a debugger (as opposed to working with pointers to strings, floats, etc. because it is useful to do so) what type should i be using? Ideally taking into consideration 32/64 bit considerations.

Some of the adhoc types i have been using upto now, in the same code, for the same purpose include int64_t, NSUInteger, char *, void *, intptr_t.

essentially i will need to compare and sort by address. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to compare addresses, using a void* should be the way to go. This will take *any* type, and the reference (`&`) operator will print out a valid memory location. On top of that, it will be portable between 32 and 64 bit types, as well as random structs, etc. etc. etc.. You can compare with a regular less-than comparison, except using the address of the pointer (`&`) rather than the value of the pointer itself.

If you need to reference the data in these pointers though, you're going to run into a bit of trouble...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a toss up between `uintptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>`) and `void *`.  Both will work equally well for both 32-bit and 64-bit environments.  I'd probably use `uintptr_t`, but you won't go far wrong with `void *` either.

Answer (score 0):

Another type which might come in handy is [`ptrdiff_t`](http://www.viva64.com/en/t/0041/). Just [be careful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david_leblanc/ptrdiff_t-is-evil).